# mapping over entire data set to get results

Tags: haskell

Suppose I have the arrays:

```
A = "ABACUS"

B = "YELLOW"
```

And they are zipped so: `Pairing = zip A B`

I also have a function `Connect :: Char -> [(Char,Char)] -> [(Char,Char,Int)]`

What I want to do is given a char such as A, find the indices of where it is present in the first string and return the character in the same positions in the second string, as well as the position e.g. if I did `Connect 'A' Pairing` I'd want (A,Y,0) and (A,L,2) as results.

I know I can do

```
pos = x!!map fst pairing
```

to retrieve the positions. And `fnd = findIndices (==pos) map snd pairing` to get what's in this position in the second string but in Haskell how would I do this over the whole set of data (as if I were using a for loop) and how would I get my outputs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do exactly as you asked (but correct the initial letter of function names to be lowercase), I could define

```
connect :: Char -> [(Char,Char)] -> [(Char,Char,Int)]
connect c pairs = [(a,b,n)|((a,b),n) <- zip pairs [0..], a == c]
```

so if

```
pairing = zip "ABACUS" "YELLOW"
```

we get

```
ghci> connect 'A' pairing
[('A','Y',0),('A','L',2)]
```

However, I think it'd be neater to zip once, not twice, using `zip3`:

```
connect3 :: Char -> String -> String -> [(Char,Char,Int)]
connect3 c xs ys = filter (\(a,_,_) -> a==c) (zip3 xs ys [0..])
```

which is equivalent to

```
connect3' c xs ys = [(a,b,n)| (a,b,n) <- zip3 xs ys [0..], a==c]
```

they all work as you wanted:

```
ghci> connect3 'A' "ABACUS" "YELLOW"
[('A','Y',0),('A','L',2)]
ghci> connect3' 'A' "ABACUS" "AQUAMARINE"
[('A','A',0),('A','U',2)]
```

---

In comments, you said you'd like to get pairs for matches the other way round.

This time, it'd be most convenient to use the monadic `do` notation, since lists are an example of a monad.

```
connectEither :: (Char,Char) -> String -> String -> [(Char,Char,Int)]
connectEither (c1,c2) xs ys = do
   (a,b,n) <- zip3 xs ys [0..]
   if  a == c1 then return (a,b,n) else
    if b == c2 then return (b,a,n) else 
     fail "Doesn't match - leave it out"
```

I've used the `fail` function to leave out ones that don't match. The three lines starting `if`, `if` and `fail` are increasingly indented because they're actually one line from Haskell's point of view.

```
ghci> connectEither ('a','n') "abacus" "banana"
[('a','b',0),('a','n',2),('n','u',4)]
```

In this case, it hasn't included `('n','a',2)` because it's only checking one way.

We can allow both ways by reusing existing functions:

```
connectBoth :: (Char,Char) -> String -> String -> [(Char,Char,Int)]
connectBoth (c1,c2) xs ys = lefts ++ rights where
      lefts  = connect3 c1 xs ys
      rights = connect3 c2 ys xs
```

which gives us everything we want to get:

```
ghci> connectBoth ('a','n') "abacus" "banana"
[('a','b',0),('a','n',2),('n','a',2),('n','u',4)]
```

but unfortunately things more than once:

```
ghci> connectBoth ('A','A') "Austria" "Antwerp"
[('A','A',0),('A','A',0)]
```

So we can get rid of that using `nub` from `Data.List`. (Add `import Data.List` at the top of your file.)

```
connectBothOnce (c1,c2) xs ys = nub $ connectBoth (c1,c2) xs ys
```

giving

```
ghci> connectBothOnce ('A','A') "ABACUS" "Antwerp"
[('A','A',0),('A','t',2)]
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to show me different approaches. Much appreciated!

Comment: In the event I had a tuple of Chars as input (Char,Char) such that
[link]connect :: (Char,Char) -> [(Char,Char)] -> [(Char,Char,Int)]
how could I have it so that it returned the pairing in the second string to the 2nd tuple also? i.e 
ghci> connect ('A','E') "ABACUS" "YELLOW" 
[('A','Y',0),('A','L',2),('E','B',1)??

Comment: Do you mean `connect ('A','E') "ABACUS" "YELLOW"` should be `[('A','Y',0),('A','L',2),('B','E',1)]`, given that the `E` is second it's for the second String? If so, you need `connect3'' (c1,c2) xs ys = [(a,b,n)| (a,b,n) <- zip3 xs ys [0..], a==c1 || b==c2]`. If not, let me know.

Comment: No I need it returned how I said. I would explain the context for why I need it like this but it'll take too long ha!

Comment: Should the answer to `connect ('A','A') "ABACUS" "ANTWERP"`be `[('A','A')]` or `[('A','A'), ('A','A')]`?

Comment: Ah fantastic. Thanks once again. You've been a great help!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend not zipping the lists together, since that'd just make it more difficult to use the function `elemIndices` from `Data.List`.  You then have a list of the indices that you can use directly to get the values out of the second list.

Answer (score 1):

You can add indices with another `zip`, then filter on the given character and convert tuples to triples. Especially because of this repackaging, a list comprehension seems appropriate:

```
connect c pairs = [(a, b, idx) | ((a, b), idx) <- zip pairs [0..], a == c]
```

Comment: Attempted solving this with a list comprehension before but ended up really confusing myself in terms of structuring the code! Where would I write the code for getting the index?